# Dynamic generation of <option> list without separate php file

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I need to create a specific `<option>` list on a form, depending on which option is selected by the user on the previuos `<select>` list. In this case, as part of a school ERP, when user selects course the system should load on the next field only the subjects related to this course.

This can be done by ajax, using the 'change' method, posting on real-time course ID, and giving back as the result of the query, the list of related subjects wich is loaded on its `<select>` list.

Is making this by having a separate file instead of trying another options the best practice to solve this cases? I mean, if the best way to do this is by having an specific file for every list that must be dinamically generated, then I'll make it this way, but I feel that having a php file for every single dynamic list that should be generated on real-time maybe is not the most efficient way to do this (got many form fields that should behave this way).

Answer (score 1):

One PHP file will do.

Use this tutorial to learn about URL parameters:
http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Combine with this tutorial on how to retrieve data from a database:
http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson20.php

---

The idea here is, using AJAX, instead of fetching your list like this:
`http://example.com/list/thing1.php`, `http://example.com/list/thing2.php`

You use a single PHP file, like this:
`http://example.com/list.php?foo=thing1`, `http://example.com/list.php?foo=thing2`

So instead of having *a php file for every single dynamic list* you can have one file that loads and format the specific data you need dynamically.

Comment: Does your answer mean that the best way would be passing variables on a URL to the same PHP file in order to reload the page and generate the list on real time? Everything contained on your links are things I know, but I dont undertand the final point of your answer. Which practice is the most efficient? Separate php file or on the same file? If it is on the same file, how? Thankl you.